# Incorrect error text when deleting multiple comments within 5 seconds

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, deleted-comments

On SO & MSO, the error message displayed when deleting two comments within 5 seconds used to be:

> Can only delete a comment every 5 seconds.

It has now been replaced with the following error, which is not as descriptive (and incorrect):

> An error occurred during voting

**Steps to Reproduce:**
 1. Add two comments
 2. Delete both comments within 5 seconds
 3. Bask in your error glory

Answer (score 6):

**Reproduced.**

I've seen this as well. **Annoying**. Why is there a 5 second rule on comment *deletion* anyway? It's not like we can delete other people's comments anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that deleting a comment is equivalent to a "**vote to delete**" process. You can only vote once every 5 seconds, hence the 5-second limitation (and possibly the non-specific error).