# Wrong message "You may only submit a comment every five seconds" when deleting multiple comments

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn’t count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

This is similar, yet different, to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19345/incorrect-error-text-when-deleting-multiple-comments-within-5-seconds). That post explains a wrong error text, which seems fixed, but fixed it is with — again — a wrong error text. It is now:

> You may only submit a comment vote every
>   five seconds

when you delete two comments within five seconds. While it could be so much clearer with *"You may only delete a comment every five seconds"*, or simply allow it (deleting a comment is unrelated to voting a comment and insensitive to abuse).

Comment: reproduces here...

Comment: Awaiting the **status-bydesign** tag any second now.

Comment: It's a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message could definitely be improved.  I don't think you'll find that @Jeff is amenable to removing it:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001228.html

Comment: Could still be left in place, just with a text alteration.

Comment: Considering how much he hates comments, you would think he would *want* to make it easier to delete lots of them in a row....