# What happened to the dialog box on deleting comments within five seconds of voting?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-voting, deleted-comments

Given the discussion here [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote) as well as many other places on meta [Wrong message "You may only submit a comment every five seconds" when deleting multiple comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31455/wrong-message-you-may-only-submit-a-comment-every-five-seconds-when-deleting-mu)  or [Confirmation dialog for deleting a comment does not appear twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47293/confirmation-dialog-for-deleting-a-comment-does-not-appear-twice) etc [Incorrect error text when deleting multiple comments within 5 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19345/incorrect-error-text-when-deleting-multiple-comments-within-5-seconds)

Why is there no longer a dialog box when I [go to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful)<sup>1</sup> delete a comment within five seconds of another comment action? Is this a regression bug?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>oh it was funny to me :p</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.comment-delete`'s click handler invokes `submiteVote()`, which makes an incorrect assumption about where you clicked. Specifically, it uses `this.jComment.find(".comment-actions")` to pass as the error target to `.ajax()`/`StackExchange.helpers.showErrorPopup()`, which only exists if the comment that you're "voting" on is not your own.

Since the target *doesn't* exist in this case, when the server returns the 409 response about rate-limiting your comment voting, the error dialog is appended to an empty jQuery set and therefore isn't visible to the user.

Comment: Oh good lord man, I knew you had an idea about the problem ...

Comment: @jcolebrand Just needed a few minutes ;)