# Deleting comments on locked posts fails silently

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, locked-questions, deleted-comments

Trying to delete your own comment from a locked post doesn't work, but there is no indication that it failed. No error message, and the comment even disappears, but of course it's back when you refresh the page.

The server returns this:

```js
{"Success":false,"Warning":false,"NewScore":0,"Message":"This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging","Refresh":false}
```

… but the UI seems to ignore it.

Comment: Looks like the same root issue as [deletion rate-limiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95942) (though the code's changed around a bit), and now there's a `.done()` callback that removes the comment irrespective of the response.

Comment: OH, it was silent but not deadly...hmm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tim Stone notes correctly, the UI removed the comment regardless of whether deletion was successful or not. That's fixed in the next build.