# Comments Are Deleted but UI is not Updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

On Meta, if you add a comment to a post, then delete it, the deletion occurs server-side but the UI is not updated. Refreshing the page however shows that the comment was indeed deleted.

This is occurring on Chrome 19 / Windows.

Comment: I was able to repro it (Chrome)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a typo in my [previous bugfix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134811/deleting-comments-on-locked-posts-fails-silently) (it turns out that JavaScript is actually case sensitive). The fix will be built out in a few minutes (the bug has only been deployed to Meta).