# Cannot delete multiple comments

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the dialog box on deleting comments within five seconds of voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95942/what-happened-to-the-dialog-box-on-deleting-comments-within-five-seconds-of-voti)

Try to delete multiple of your own comments from the same answer. Only the first one succeeds. This is a bug.

I have seen other bugs similar to this one, but I can't remember right now. It's probably worth to do a little testing in this area.

Comment: Quick! Everyone try it here!

Comment: You can delete the comments, you just have to wait five seconds in between. The bug is that you aren't told that you have to wait five seconds.