# Rate-limited comment deletions fail silently

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the dialog box on deleting comments within five seconds of voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95942/what-happened-to-the-dialog-box-on-deleting-comments-within-five-seconds-of-voti)

When deleting multiple comments in quick succession, the first one is fine but the others fail silently.

I still get the following delete confirmation box, but nothing happens after I click `[ok]`. No warnings, no deletion, nada.

[image: click, but nothing happened]

If I wait 5 seconds between deletes, all is well so I guess comment deletion is subject to the same rate limits as comment posting. But shouldn't there be an error/warning messaging stating so?

p.s. Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49268/minor-bug-when-i-delete-another-comment-too-quickly-it-says) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19345/incorrect-error-text-when-deleting-multiple-comments-within-5-seconds) (and several others), we used to have a warning message for this albeit a confusing one.

Comment: what theme is that?

Comment: @jcolebrand theme? IIRC, that was on FF9, vanilla.

Comment: Ok, what site? That doesn't look like any of the sites I've seen on the SE network (or I don't pay enough attention to delete comment dialogs?)

Comment: @jcolebrand that was here on MSO.

Comment: I should use more Firefox then I suppose.